# Code::Blocks_Linker error unable to find C0X32.obj

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks IDE for writing C++ programmes with Borland 5.5 as a compiler.
When I build a programme it shows:
'Fatal: Unable to open file 'C0X32.OBJ'

I searched online and they said that I should include it's path in the Linker settings under 'Compiler and Debugger' under the Properties tab.

I did that but the error persists.

Also, in the build log, it shows, along with other lib files, the path for C0X32.obj:
'
   -------------- Clean: Debug in Proj ---------------

Cleaned "Proj - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in Proj ---------------

```
bcc32.exe -q -w -x  -v    -I"C:\Program Files\Borland\BDS\4.0\include" -  
IC:\Borland\BCC55\Include -IC:\Borland\BCC55\Bin -IC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib -
IC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib\PSDK  -oobj\Debug\main.obj -c main.cpp
main.cpp:

bcc32.exe -q -w -x  -v    -I"C:\Program Files\Borland\BDS\4.0\include" -
IC:\Borland\BCC55\Include -IC:\Borland\BCC55\Bin -IC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib -
IC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib\PSDK  -oobj\Debug\Helloworld.obj -c Helloworld.cpp
Helloworld.cpp:
```

//there are other lib files mentioned here.Basically all the files present in the lib folder which I included in the linker settings.
........
   C:\Borland\BCC55\Lib\C0X32.OBJ

I don't understand, C0X32.obj is present, it's coming in the build log, but it's still showing unable to find C0X32.obj.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In Borland IDE, click on Options-->Project-->Directories and put complete path in the Include and Library fields as C:\Borland\BCC55\include   and  C:\Borland\BCC55\lib   respectively ( Normally, only "C:" is missing from the complete path).  Click Ok to save changes. You are done and ready to use the compiler.

This problem may occur when there are some problems (reported) during the installation and the complete path could not be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the compilation on the command line, which is what I seem to be doing, then the solution is quite simple: use, as compiler command line (bcc32.exe), the -L option, to refer to directory where the compiler libraries are located.
Looking at your compile command line, we clearly notice that you are using the -I option, and therefore just change it to -L (-LC:\Borland\BCC55\Lib).